# Can we set our own date format to database? I just need to save mm/yy in my database

Tags: database, date, playframework

I am using the Play framework and I want to use my own date format to save the date as mm/yy in the database. For example: If I have the date as 12/08/1991 then I want to save 08/1991 in database.

I have tried using date formatter but the only thing that has been successful is by storing the date as string in the database. But I need to set the date as date in database too. (i.e. Need a column/field that is a date type.)

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the technologies you're using? I believe I understand the question and have attempted to provide an answer but the phrase `I am using play ...` in the OP does not mean anything to me. What is `play` and why is it so important to the question that it's the very first thing mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Do note that a column/field of type date does not have any intrinsic formatting in database persistence or in programming in general. It is a data type comprised of a year, month and day and can easily be represented internally by a single integer or many other ways. Formatting of the date information only takes place when the date is processed for display or when you need to compare the date to another date from a different system but that's not really formatting, it's conversion.

That said, you have several options:

- The simplest is to just use a single date column and then manage your formatting of the date data on the client/GUI side (or in your data model per some business rule)
- You can also create two date columns: One column for your custom date value stored as a string and another column for the actual date type and value

I only brought up the 2nd option above to show that there are several ways to get this done. But a good rule of thumb when designing databases is to not store formatted data. Data formatting is a presentation-level consideration. I.E. formatted data is meant for viewing by an end-user. That consideration, if stored in the db at all, would be assigned at the user level and not to the data that is being displayed by the user.

For an example, say you needed to display a date based on a user's timezone. You would not want to create and store different date values based on your users' needs. You would save the user's preferred timezone and then format/convert a base date (GMT/UTC) per that setting.